# Java: How can I get a deterministic method result when it is launched from a user interface?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using java to process simulations,
If I launch the the simulation from a static main function, everything is deterministic and I get the same simulation each time I hit Run as -> Java application, even if I close and reopen eclipse, which is enough to debug the program.

But when I launch the simulation from a GUI (with libgdx) with the same parameters multiple times, the result does change each time.

I Suspect that the code executed during the GUI is not exactly the same (because I am not a robot) which causes some classes such as HashSet to have non deterministic iterations.

How can I get the same behavior as the static main method?

Any advice would be much appreciated

Edit: as code was asked, there is an instance of the issue:

```java
public class Test{
    private static final int n = 4;
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {
        // random HashSet in my GUI uses Object.hashcode
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            new Test().hashCode();
        }
        // at some point launches the simulation
        simulation();
    }

    public static void simulation()
    {
        // HashSet anywere in the simulation uses hashcode
        System.out.println(new Test().hashCode());
    }
}
```

The result of simulation() depends on n (on what happened during the GUI), so i just would like to get rid of the GUI's influence and run the static method simulation separately, but how?

Comment: At a guess you are relying on things that Java does not guarantee - HashSet for example does not guarantee the iteration order of the members. But without code we can only guess.

Comment: i know that Java does not guarantee this behavior, but it turns out that running the same code from the start of a public static main(final String[] args) method gives the same result, even if there is HashSet iterations. You can test that on the code i sent, it does that on my very messy simulations (with many hash sets, loads of garbage collector operations). I don't need the iteration order of the HashSet to be consistent through the simulation, i just need that the same simulation with the same parameters gives the same result/error for debugging purposes.

Comment: Watch your code formatting. Either indent all lines by four spaces, or wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks. I fixed it this time for you.

Comment: An easy way to test if it is the `HashSet` that is causing the change of behaviour is to change it to a `TreeSet` and see if you get the same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Object#hashCode` may vary between runs

Your code is calling the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method on an instance of your `Test` class, a method inherited from [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html).

Implementations of Java commonly implement that method by hashing the equivalent of a memory address of the object, or some such value. To quote the Javadoc of `Object#hashCode`.

> The hashCode may or may not be implemented as some function of an object's memory address at some point in time.

While not necessarily so, if the implementation is using a memory-address scheme, one can imagine that successive runs of a console app might end up with the same hash code value on each run. But you certainly should not expect that. To quote the Javadoc:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

In contrast to a console app, a GUI app is much more complicated, interacting with the host OS to establish windows, menus, and such. One can imagine here that the objects established on an execution run of the GUI app might result in somewhat different objects, enough so that hash codes calculated from something related to memory layout may well vary between runs.

You said:

> If I launch the the simulation from a static main function, everything is deterministic and I get the same simulation each time I hit Run as -> Java application

As the last sentence of the above quoted Javadoc says: **You may, or may not, get the same hash code** on separate runs of your app.

➥ At the end of the day, none of this matters. **You should not rely on the same value being returned from `hashCode` method** between executions of your app. You can only rely on the same hash code *during* an execution of the app.

So your question, “How can I get the same behavior as the static main method?”, is moot. **You should not be expecting the same hash code** between runs. Why not? Because the documentation says so.

## UUID

Reading between the lines, I guess you are trying to use the hash code value as a permanent unique identifier. That is *not* the purpose of a hash code.

Instead, consider using a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Java bundles the [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) class to represent these 128-bit values.

If you want to specify a UUID value for your object, you can construct one using a factory method that parses the canonical textual presentation as a hex string with hyphen-delimited groupings of digits. You can manually generate a few values with a web site such as [this](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version1). Or use software to manually generate UUID values.

```java
record Dog ( UUID id , String name ) {}
Dog spot = 
    new Dog( 
        UUID.fromString( "05ffbad6-b75b-11eb-8529-0242ac130003" ) , 
        "Spot" 
    ) 
;
```

In using [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16, the compiler automatically overrides the `equals` and `hashCode` methods inherited from `Object` by using each and every member field.

Alternatively, with a `UUID` as an identifier, you may well want to use only that one member field for your `equals`/`hashCode`. In such a case, manually override those two methods yourself. Ditto for a conventional class in place of a record.

```java
public record Dog( UUID id , String name )
{
    @Override
    public boolean equals ( final Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        final Dog dog = ( Dog ) o;
        return id.equals( dog.id );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( id );
    }
}
```

With those overrides in place, misspellings on the dog's name would not count for equality or hashCode.

```java
Dog x =
        new Dog(
                UUID.fromString( "05ffbad6-b75b-11eb-8529-0242ac130003" ) ,
                "Spot"
        );
Dog y =
        new Dog(
                UUID.fromString( "05ffbad6-b75b-11eb-8529-0242ac130003" ) ,
                "spoht"
        );

boolean sameDog = x.equals( y );
boolean sameHashCode = ( x.hashCode() == y.hashCode() );
```

> sameDog = true

> sameHashCode = true

Comment: So if I want to debug, the correct way to go is replacing all the HashSet of my project by LinkedHashSet until i am done? And hunting down stream.findany() too i guess

Comment: I though that the JVM which uses it's own virtual object memory adress could erase the non deterministic behavior of hardware memory, and do this job for me

Comment: @Fogux No. You can use `HashSet` or any other code depending on a reliable `hashCode` by using the default `hashCode` implementation — *during* a single run of your app. The problem is that you are choosing to expect a stable value returned from `hashCode` *between* runs of your app. As I explained in the Answer, your expectation is unreasonable. The documentation tells you explicitly to not expect that behavior.

Comment: @Fogux You *really* need to go back to the Javadoc of [`Object#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), and read very carefully.

Comment: @Fogux Your second comment is entirely irrelevant because the inner workings of `Object#hashCode` is an **implementation detail** that is none of your business nor mine. Limit your expectations to the behavior promised by the Javadoc, nothing more.

Comment: I'm not willing to use hashCode as an UUID or to rely on the value in my project, It is just convenient to debug code with the eclipse debug feature if it runs in the same way at each execution (which it does in spite of the javadoc unless I am using the GUI of course hence the initial post) so i might still use this forbidden feature which should not exist to debug my code.